# Probability of Same Choice Twice

Tags: probability

I have a list with 3 colors on it:

- Red
- Green
- Blue

One of the colors is randomly chosen... Say Blue.

If a random color is selected from the same list 10 more times, what is the probability that Blue will be selected again at least one more time?

Comment: Try calculating the complementary probability, that is, calculate the probability that none of the ten selections are blue.

Comment: An least once is the same thing as not none.  $1-(\frac 23)^{10}$

Comment: OK - I believe that I understand what is being suggested here... For the general case of list size N and # of choices C, the value would be 1 - ((N - 1) / N) ^ C.  (Sorry, I am not too great at LaTeX syntax).

Comment: $1-\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^C$ Yes. \$`1-\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^C`\$